# what is "(post) /api/projects - post file to oss and requested translation"

Tags: autodesk-forge

like this,I can not solve this problem,who can help me

[image]

Comment: This is snapshot is showing the unit test result of the project, is there any specific reason that you didn't want to access the project via web browser directly?

Comment: yes, I want to get the svf files,but i can not run the project successfully.because have error.(TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
    at C:\Users\admin\Downloads\extract.autodesk.io-mastertest\extract.autodesk.io-master\server\recaptcha.js:38:17
    at Request.handleRequestResponse [as _callback] (C:\Users\admin\Downloads\extract.autodesk.io-mastertest\extract.autodesk.io-master\node_modules\unirest\index.js:355:15)
    at self.callback

Comment: With my old memory, this project is not compatible with the Windows, I would advise you to host it on a Unix like system. There are many free web hosting, e.g. cloud 9, heroku and etc. I will find time to test on Windows at my end later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download your own Forge extracted files, I would advise you use those approaches instead:

1. Nodejs: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs
2. C#: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net
3. PHP: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/php-sample-extract-svf